# data.table group by 2 weeks or 6 months

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table where I have several columns with number of items, date, etc. However I would like to group some sums by a period of 2 weeks or 6 months. I have already applied the grouping by week, 1 month and quarter as follows:

```
total.national.sales.by.category <- table[, sum(total_price), 
                                          by= .(week(local_created_day),category)]
```

where `local_created_Day` is the date column and `total_price` is just a numeric value column.

However, I would like to group the table by periods of 2 weeks or 6 months, but there is no built in function in data.table to do it (ex. in data.table you put quarter(local_created_Day) in the 'by' statement and it group it by 3 month period or by 'week()' and it groups it by week).

The `local_created_Day` column format is something like '2019-08-07' as Date object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is `Date` class, one option is to create the weekly grouping with `cut`.  According to `?cut.Date`

> breaks - a vector of cut points or number giving the number of intervals which x is to be cut into or an interval specification, one of "sec", "min", "hour", "day", "DSTday", "week", "month", "quarter" or "year", optionally preceded by an integer and a space, or followed by "s". (For "Date" objects only interval specifications using "day", "week", "month", "quarter" and "year" are allowed.

```
library(data.table)
table[, .(PriceSum = sum(total_price)), by= .(weekgrp = cut(local_created_day,
                   breaks = "2 week"),category)]
```

---

Using a reproducible example

```
set.seed(24)   
dt <- data.table(local_created_day = Sys.Date() + 1:48, 
 category = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 48, replace = TRUE), 
 total_price = rnorm(48))
dt[, .(PriceSum = sum(total_price)), by= .(weekgrp = cut(local_created_day,
                breaks = "2 week"),category)]
```